# Opening two instances of two different flavors but same code base

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I am experiencing the following situation:
Application A is in the background, then I launch application B from the relevant icon, but A reopens.

Both flavors share most of the same code.

The problem is, both A and B opening the same MainActivity file. the MainActivity located in the `main` package and not inside the flavors packages. I want each flavor to open a new task for itself.

this is the current XML files:

A:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">   
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

B:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">   
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and build.grade:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
       ...
    }

flavorDimensions "example"
productFlavors {
    a{
        dimension "example"
        applicationIdSuffix ".a"
        versionCode ...
        versionName ...

        //flavor consts
       ...
    }

    b{
        dimension "example"
        applicationIdSuffix ".b"
        versionCode ...
        versionName ...

        //flavor consts
        ...
    }
}
```

I was trying to switch the **launchMode** into a standard but it didn't do any good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had another field that wasn't mentioned:

```
        android:taskAffinity="..."
```

both flavors used the same task Affinity application class, so I cut it into two separated Applications classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you taskAffinity references your applicationId, it will only open as one instance. Try:

```
android:taskAffinity="${applicationId}"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).